# Safety Capacitor replacement

Tags: capacitor, identification

I am trying to repair sewing machine by replacing a safety capacitor that burned up. I am not at all sure how to find an equivalent capacitor. Advice or links to an appropriate product would be appreciated.

[image: capacitor]

info from capacitor body:

RIFA 40/085/56 GPC
PME 271 M 610
250V~MP fo=4,9 Mhz  X2

Comment: A straight 2.7 uF X2 capacitor should be easy to find.

Comment: Type the P/N on the cap into Octopart.com

Comment: @user: Why do you call this a "safety capacitor"? It's there to filter out noise and/or to reduce sparking and electromagnetic interference.

Comment: @Transistor Because of its X2 rating.

Answer (score 5):

The Rifa legacy and new Kemet codes are as follows: -

[image]

[Here's](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiWk7rl0vTcAhWnLcAKHbCGBpMQFjABegQICBAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.farnell.com%2Fdatasheets%2F1886898.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1wcdBdDwzI7Cj1b1FSVjSx) the datasheet. Part available from Farnell most likely or the modern Kemet version.

Answer (score 5):

It's a PME271M-40/085/56 0.1uF X2 safety capacitor. You can buy a direct replacement [from Radwell International](https://www.radwell.com/en-US/Buy/RIFA/RIFA/PME271M-40-DIV-085-DIV-56) (scroll down to "NEVER USED Surplus Level 2") for $0.85 a pop plus shipping.

You could also order [pretty much any one of these from Digi-Key.](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/capacitors/film-capacitors/62?k=&pkeyword=&pv707=173&FV=fff80010%2Cfff800ed%2C1c0011%2C1c0002%2C1c00fa%2C1c0003%2C14300001%2C1430000a%2C1430006b%2C14300071%2C14300074%2C14300075%2C14300076%2C14300077%2C14300078%2C14300079%2C1430007a%2C1430007c%2C1430009e%2C143000a0%2C143000a1%2C143000a2%2C143000a3%2C143000a8%2C143000a9%2C143000ab%2C143000ac%2C1430001b%2C1430001c%2C1430001d%2C1430001e%2C1430001f%2C14300021%2C14300023%2C14300024%2C14300026%2C14300027%2C14300028%2C14300029%2C1430002c%2C1430002d%2C1430002e%2C14300030%2C14300031%2C14300032%2C14300034%2C14300035%2C14300036%2C14300038%2C1430003b%2C14300006%2C1430003c%2C1430003e%2C14300040%2C14300041%2C14300043%2C14300044%2C14300045%2C14300046%2C14300054%2C14300055%2C14300056%2C14300057%2C14300058%2C1430005a%2C1430005b%2C1430005c%2C1430005d%2C1430005e%2C1430005f%2C1f140000%2Cffe0003e%2Cmu0.1%C2%B5F%7C2049&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25)

[Here's another direct replacement on Digi-Key](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/kemet/PME271MB6100KR30/399-7489-ND/3459460) (made by KEMET) for $1.82 plus shipping.

Answer (score 3):

That RIFA part series has been a problem child for many years, so you may not want a direct replacement.  However, any X2 capacitor of the same value (more or less) will do just fine.  Many people make them and any distributor will sell them.  You might even find them on Amazon.